# Find all words/string in an expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Lets say I have expression like

```
$string = ( score + total-score - total-min_score) / papoy
```

I want to able to extract those ALL words/term into an array   ( words with/without dash and underscore )

I tried like  (I'm not so good with regex)

```
preg_match("(\w+-_)",$string,$matches);
```

But it only return me the first match. How could I get all matches?

Comment: use preg_match_all and what would be your expected output?

Comment: oh yes preg_match_all is thing I looking for, BUT it seems my regex is not working properly to include dash and underscore. How can i correct that. Its returning empty result http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/abf

Comment: You know that `\w` also matches digits, right?

Comment: Oops didn't know that. String like 'total991' is fine but only digits '991' won't be fine for me. Anyway I can check for that letter once i get an array :) . An edited @AvinashRaj regex will be very appreciated though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use preg_match_all function.

```
preg_match_all('~[\w-]+~',$string,$matches);
```

OR

```
preg_match_all('~\w+(?:-\w+)*~', $string, $matches);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nP6wM5/2)

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats latter one is perfect. It eliminate the single 'dash' result from the former regex.